# For loop continuing past desired point and automating splitting of text that's too long

Tags: r

I have a couple questions about this specific bit of code. My boss passed on some code he'd used for a different project and I'm not the most fluent in R but modified it to work with our data sheets. I ended up with what's below:

```
l<-matrix(nrow=(ceiling(length(d[,1])/11))*5,ncol=11)
k<-1

for (j in ((c(1:(length(l[,1])/5))*5)-4)){

 for (i in c(1:11)) {  
  l[j,i]<-paste(d[k,"Locality"])
  l[j+1,i]<-paste(d[k,"Plot"]) 
  l[j+2,i]<-paste(d[k,"Coordinates"])
  l[j+3,i]<-paste(d[k,"Method"],"-",d[k,"Date"])
  l[j+4,i]<-paste(d[k,"Field_collector"]," ",d[k,"Number"])
  
  if (k < length(d[,1])) k<-k+1
```

It runs fine but runs a little longer than I want to it. It's meant to spit out 11 columns of labels and, for example, if the last row of labels only fills 9 of those columns the code will duplicate the last label two extra times to fill in all 11 spaces on that row. So far I've just been manually erasing the extra labels which has been fine but my boss said his original code didn't do that (and has no idea why mine does) so I know it's fixable.

Second question: I want to use this same code for plant labels. The label would be the same except the first 4 rows are blank and the last is the plant species. Well, some plant names are too long and don't print well when restricted to one row. One option would be set some character limit but I would be afraid of splitting mid-name and pretty consistently plant names that are too long have "var." in their name. When doing it manually I like splitting them before the "var." EX:
row 4. Lythrum alatum
row 5. var. lanceolatum

I was wondering if there was a way to build that split into the for loop or just run the data sheet through some code that splits a species name when there is a "var." before it goes through the label making code.

Comment: Can you provide some example data that works and samples that don't work as expected?

Comment: The nicest way to provide sample data is `dput()`. If you have data `d`, then `dput(d[1:11, 1:7])` creates a copy/pasteable version of the first 11 rows and first 7 columns of `d`. If you could run that and edit the result into your question, and also show what the desired output is for that result, it would help us a lot to understand. Choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem if my guess of the first 11 rows and 7 columns isn't a good one.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250754/5224236